# Conditionally Replacing Values in a Dataframe Column Based on Values in Another Dataframe Column Using Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)  

Column1<-c("Course1","Course1","Course1","Course2","Course2","Course3","Course3","Course3","    Course4","Course4","Course5","Course5")
Column2<-c("Cat","Dog","Snake","Elephant","Beaver","Rabbit","Fish","Bird","Bear","Horse","Raccoon","Skunk")
Df1<-data.frame(Column1,Column2)
```

Using the sample data above, I want to conditionally replace/recode the value of "Column1" based on the values of "Column2".

For this simple example, if "Column2" contains "Cat" or "Dog", then the "Column1" value should be replaced with "Course6".

So far, I've tried the code below. It doesn't work, but I feel like I'm close. I would also prefer a tidyverse solution.

```
map2(Df1[2],Df1[1],~if_else(.x =="Cat"|"Dog", replace(.y, "Course6")))

map2(Df1[2],Df1[1],~if_else(.x =="Cat"|"Dog", replace(.y, .x,"Course6")))
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I get you right but maybe this works for you:

```
df1[df1$Column2 == c("Cat", "Dog"), 1] <- "Course6"
```

When you create the dataframe you have to turn off `stringsAsFactors` or provide a complete list of factors.

**EDIT**

A bit more `tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>%
  spread(key = Column2, value = Column1) %>%
  mutate("Dog" = "Course6") %>%
  gather(key = "Column1", value = "Column2")
```

Comment: How would I write this tidyverse style using dplyr in a pipe?